# How to list all the apps from Google Play Store on python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

This is more of a conceptual question than a technical one:

I want to create a crawler that will list of the apps on the Google App Store under the shopping category (`https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/SHOPPING?hl=en_US&gl=US`). The problem is: this page has 4 main sections: `Top Free`, `Top Grossing`, `Trending` and `Top Paid`.

But I need a way to collect ALL THE APPS for a given country. The problem is: I can't find a way to list all of them. Does any of you have ever coded something like this or know any library that could do it?

Thanks